# Download large application data pattern

Tags: android, download, android-sdcard, large-data

I am developing a map rendering application for Android. The map data is quite big about 1.1 Gb. Since there are limits both in the market and in the phone for .apk size the recommendations is to download it when application starts.

**This is the pattern I use now:**
1. Main activity (used for rendering the map) checks if the data is avaiable, if not i starts a download activity
2. The download activity starts a local service
3. The service downloads the zip files and unpacks the mapdata
4. The service sends events to the download activity and notifications

I spawn a service since the whole process can take some time from 30min to a couple of hours depending on phone and network.

But I have trouble making sure that only one instance of the program is running, I have tried all combinations of the launchmode property to no help.

As you may understand two instances running will crash the download/unzip.

*This is really frustrating! Now I am doing some ugly read/write to sdcard file lock and it is working most of the time to make sure only one instance is running.*

I am targeting Android 1.6 and above.

Comment: Are you sure that you need send 1.1 Gb to the user phone? Buffering the result and sending it when it needs is not a better solution?

Comment: Off line mode is a requirement.

Comment: Suppose I have **GPRS (not 3G/Wifi/EDGE)** connection and want to use your application, then can you imagine when it will be able to download this huge file?. _I would recommend try to consider worst conditions._

Comment: Thanks for the input, but it is stated in the program description (in market) that you need to download the data after the install. I hope the users will respect and understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid problems with multiple instances, you should use [remote service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#RemoteMessengerServiceSample) instead of local service. This way, you can have only one instance of the service which will download data you need for the application.

Comment: No easy way out? I don't know much about remote services, but it sounds like overkill. Starting up a remote service just for downloading some files and unzipping them. Gahhh! I will of course check it out, thanks.

Comment: Actually, they are not as complicated as they seem to be at first sight, but it takes some time to get used to some concepts... Once you start using them, you will love them...

Comment: I have tried it out now. Maybe something is not configured correct. When I press back in my download activity (finishes the application) the service is stopped (`onDestory` is called). It would be nice if the download still continues in the background, any ideas? But it seems to handle the case of multiple instances better.

Comment: How do you start the service? Also, maybe you call close in your  activity in onPause method? My call to service is:               startService(new Intent(this, DataService.class));
        bindService(new     Intent(IDataServiceBinder.class.getName()),mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

Comment: The startService part did the trick, thank you! (I was just binding, not explicitly starting the service)

Answer (score 0):

1.1GB to a mobile device is a huge amount of data. Even over wifi, unless the connection is pretty good it's going to take time, as you said, and also affect the phone's performance. I'd expect the user's experience to be bad - their phone is going to be slow during the download, probably unusable during the unpacking of so much data, and the app itself won't be usable at all until the data has been downloaded in full (which may take several retries).

If it were me I'd be looking for a way to break the data down, perhaps by geographic region, and download it in packages. That way if a package download fails the app can retry, and the user can still, to some degree, use the app. You said your app is a mapping app, so perhaps you can identify the user's location/country and download the most suitable package first. Whether this will work will come down to whether there's no way at all the user can make any use of the app without ALL the data.

The issue is that Android apps may be GC'd at any point, so your requirement to have an app running for a relatively long period of time doing intensive work, but in the background, are competing. All the user needs to do is open a big app like the Browser and your service may well get shut down. By having a single massive download transaction you're backing yourself into a corner.

Alternatively, could you provide the data physically on an SD card? It's not a great solution, but given the size of your dataset it seems worth considering.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, I am already splitting up the download to about 200 3mb parts, thats not a big issue. If the download is interrupted it will resume from the latest good part. The problem is that sometimes I get multiple instances and will double download parts (extremly slow) and ultimately try to unpack multiple zip files to the same destination which of course wont work.